# It is possible to recognize all objects from a room with Microsoft Kinect?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a project where I have to recognize an entire room so I can calculate the distances between objects (like big ones eg. bed, table, etc.) and a person in that room. It is possible something like that using Microsoft Kinect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinect provides you following

1. Depth Stream
2. Color Stream
3. Skeleton information

Its up to you how you use this data.

To answer your question - Official Micorosft Kinect SDK doesnt provides shape detection out of the box. But it does provide you skeleton data/face tracking with which you can detect distance of user from kinect.
Also with mapping color stream to depth stream you can detect how far a particular pixel is from kinect. In your implementation if you have unique characteristics of different objects like color,shape and size you can probably detect them and also detect the distance.

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is one of the library that i use for computer vision etc.

Again its up to you how you use this data.

Answer (score 0):

Kinect camera provides depth and consequently 3D information (point cloud) about matte objects in the range 0.5-10 meters. With this information it is possible to segment out the floor (by fitting a plane) of the room and possibly walls and the ceiling. This step is important since these surfaces often connect separate objects making them a one big object.

The remaining parts of point cloud can be segmented by depth if they don't touch each other physically. Using color one can separate the objects even further. Note that we implicitly define an object as 3D dense and color consistent entity while other definitions are also possible.

As soon as you have your objects segmented you can measure the distances between your segments, analyse their shape, recognize artifacts or humans, etc. To the best of my knowledge however a Skeleton library can recognize humans after they moved for a few seconds. Below is a simple depth map that was broken on a few segments using depth but not color information. [image: depth] [image]